# How I handle duplicated record in textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a code for auto complete textbox in vb.net.

I have textbox search for the company name in 'company_list' table.
But some company have exactly same name, so when I input the name, it shows just 1 text.

I'd like to make these two names when I input the textbox.
Below is my code.

```
Dim sql as String = "SELECT * FROM company_info"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

con.Open()
adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable
adapter.Fill(dt)

cName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()

For Each r In dt.Rows
    cName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(r.item(1).ToString)
Next
con.Close()
```

I have two same company name as below.

[TKTech]
[TKTech]

These two are totally different company with same name, so I need to choice between them.

When I input to textbox(cName), it just show 1 name for these company.

Please let me know how I handle it.

Thank you in advance.

Frank

Comment: How can that actually be useful? Even if you do put both instances in your auto-complete list, it's still just the text.  Once you have selected one of those items from the list, the `TextBox` just contains the name selected, with no indication of which item you selected to get that text.  It sounds like you actually need a `ComboBox` and use the drop-down list as the auto-complete source. If the user selects a duplicate item then you can prompt them to explicitly select which item they actually meant.

Comment: Then in this case, it would be better to use ComboBox, instead of TextBox? After I select the item between these, it calls company_id value in database by its name. So I have to be distinguished. I'll try another way and I have no experience programming before...! Your comment is very kind. Thanks jmcihinney!

Comment: That's why you should use a `ComboBox`, because it can display the name but also expose the ID of the selected item via its `SelectedValue` property.  That way, you don't have to retrieve the record by name because you've got the ID. In fact, you already have the record because will be the `SelectedItem`.  As I said, if you use a `ComboBox` then you may well be able to determine that they have selected a value that has multiple matches and pop-up a form that allows them to select the specific item they want using more than one column for identification.

Comment: I guess the other option is to stick with the `TextBox` and then pull back all matching records when they make a selection.  If there's only one match then use it but if there are multiple, display them all in a popup and ask the user to select one, then use that.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness help!